# Renaming the startup disks shown during boot

Tags: startup

I'm dual booting OS X (Lion) and Arch Linux, and when I hold down "option" during the boot process, I am presented with both of my startup disk options (i.e., OS X and Linux); however, they are named "IluvatarHD" and "Windows". Does anybody know of a way to rename the "Windows" option to something more accurate.

I assume this is on the Mac OS X side as nowhere on my Arch install is the label "Windows"  applied.

In an ideal world, I would be able to change the disk icon as well...

NOTE: I've uninstalled refit as it's unnecessary once Arch has been installed and would rather keep using the Apple boot loader.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible to cd into /Volumes via the Terminal and then use 'sudo mv Windows (or whatever it is called there) Arch Linux'?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing the subtleties here, but it should be as simple as:

```
diskutil rename /Volumes/oldvolumename newvolumename
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this isn't possible.  The EFI boot loader just assumes that if it isn't an OS X partition then it must be Windows.

Comment: I don't think this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in Terminal if you can mount the devices directly in MacOSX

```
sudo bless --folder "volume_path" -label "volume_label"
```

Otherwise try the following option:

```
sudo bless --device "device_path" -label "volume_label"
```

found it via apples man pages: [Bless Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/bless.8.html).

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk of the Mac bootloader. While Mac and newer Windows volumes are booted via the native EFI system, older operating systems (like Windows XP and 32-bit Windows 7) require BIOS support to boot, which is provided in the firmware by the CSM ([compatibility support module](http://refit.sourceforge.net/info/boot_process.html)). Any volumes that are bootable via BIOS are always shown with the label "Windows".