# Rename EFI boot entries (MacBook Air)

Tags: startup, efi

I can't figure out how to **rename boot entries** on a MacBook Air 2012, i.e. those that appear when holding `alt` during boot.

The problem was initially that my EFI Ubuntu installation could only be booted with the boot entry called "EFI Boot", which wasn't very descriptive, but I could live with it. The current problem is that since I installed [OpenCore](https://github.innominds.com/dortania/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher) (a third party boot loader that enables Big Sur on this Macbook model) it *replaced* the Ubuntu boot entry with its own entry, which uses the same name ("EFI Boot"). I'm assuming this replacement happened because of the name collision (?).

As I see it, the first step of the solution would then be to **change the name of the current "EFI Boot" entry** (that starts OpenCore) so that when I try to recreate the Ubuntu boot entry later the OpenCore entry won't get overwritten. I can't figure out how to do this.

---

##### What I've tried

I've tried customizing [a suggestion from Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251848906) that advised how to do it for an Ubuntu `.efi` (after mounting the ESP):

```
sudo  bless  --folder  /Volumes/EFI/EFI   --file  /Volumes/EFI/EFI/OC/OpenCore.efi  --label  "OpenCore"  --shortform  --verbose
```

The above command succeeded (in Big Sur), but had no discernible effect on the boot menu upon reboot.

---

##### Related

I have also read several suggestions that I'm struggling to make sense/use of:

1. [One answer only pertains to macOS (Monterey)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437016), and explains that its `boot.efi` resides on an APFS volume. To me it appears that — on my machine — there's a `boot.efi` on my ESP (FAT32) in `/System/Library/CoreServices`, so I don't think I can make use of that even if my goal were to rename an entry for macOS (which it isn't).
2. [Another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83930) suggests that you'd just have to rename the volume an OS resides on, but I'm not trying to rename a boot entry corresponding to an OS on a particular volume. Even if I were, the answer implies mounting (?) a Linux filesystem as a volume in macOS, which isn't something that's readily available.
3. [The third answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343987) says that `.VolumeIcons.icns` should be on a Mac OS Extended formatted volume, and the name of such a volume will appear in the boot menu. I have no such volumes — only FAT32 (ESP), APFS (Mojave, Big Sur), NTFS (Windows 10) and EXT4 (Ubuntu). I have a `.VolumeIcon.icns` on the ESP though. But I still can't make sense of it since the question asks about renaming a boot entry for Windows, which I doubt is installed on Mac OS Extended. Even if it were, the entry I want to rename doesn't have its own volume to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with the less-specific volume setup - Boot Camp volume label won't get changed despite `%disk_label%` files are being successfully created (where they are supposed to be created). [You can have a look in a similar question of mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/444554/). **It appears to me that there's a firmware bug that causes this behavior.** Quite similar issue was introduced in firmware updates in about macOS Big Sur 11.3 release: `.VolumeIcon.icns` file in placed to root of `/Volumes/EFI` were not respected by Startup Manager (so no custom volume icons in Startup Manager were displayed). [Only firmware update fixed this](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2294135/).

Meanwhile please keep this question posted if you'll stumble upon a fix.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/326669)